# Vuze default meta search template missing or broken?

Tags: linux, search, bittorrent, p2p, vuze

Old versions of Vuze have worked on this computer, on this network, fine, up to just the other day -- until a clean install of Linux.

Vuze 5.2.0.0 has a good connection:

```
Pausing downloads before performing test...................................................
TCP/Web100 Network Diagnostic Tool v3.6.2b
** Starting test 1 of 1 **
Connecting to 'ndt.iupui.donar.measurement-lab.org' [ndt.iupui.donar.measurement-lab.org/4.71.251.160] to run test
Connected to: ndt.iupui.donar.measurement-lab.org--  Using IPv4 address
Checking for Middleboxes  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
Done.
Checking for firewalls . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
Done.
running 10s outbound test (client-to-server [C2S]) . . . . .
536.0kb/s
running 10s inbound test (server-to-client [S2C]) . . . . . .
9.99Mb/s
Your Workstation is connected to a
Cable/DSL modem
Information: Other network traffic is congesting the link
Completed: up=65.4 kB/s, down=1.19 MB/s
```

But there are **no** results for any search.  The [vuze wiki](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/FAQ_Meta_Search#Vuze.C2.AE_Default_Meta_Search_Templates) says:

> Vuze® Default Meta Search Templates
>
> By default Vuze searches a limited set of torrent sites. This feature,
>   whereby Vuze has enabled a select few search templates of a limited
>   set of torrent sites, is provided as a convenience to Vuze users.

I think I'm missing a template?  How can that be, it's exactly what I downloaded from vuze.com -- presumably it comes configured.

whereas I'm just not seeing this at all:

[image]

There are **no** search results for **any** search term from within Vuze itself.

When I ran an old version of Vuze (from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) it would automatically search a "limited set of torrent sites".  (The same computer on the same network, I've since done a clean install.)

While it's possible to add a template, as per the [Vuze Forums](http://forum.vuze.com/message.jspa?messageID=279816#279816):

[image]

This doesn't change the search results.

Comment: Same problem here - clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 and vuze. Result - an empty meta search window.
Adding templates does not help.
Sorry for not providing a solution but from my previous experience and a look at the log - I would say that it is an SWT issue. which has to be addressed by the developers. Dmitry